# Created a function but it is effecting the mutate function in Tidyverse somehow- why?

Tags: r, function, tidyverse

Created this function. It is suppose to take a dataframe and the name column, find certain names and change them to the new name (ex. 'OAK'~'LV').

```
names <- function(dataframe,name_column){dataframe <- dataframe %>%
  mutate(
    name_column = case_when(
      name_column == 'OAK' ~ 'LV',
      name_column == 'SD' ~ 'LAC',
      name_column == 'STL' ~ 'LA',
      TRUE ~ name_column
    ))}
```

But I get an error when I try to use mutate in a regular line of code.

```
passatt <- pbp %>% select(posteam, pass_attempt, yards_gained,game_date, sack) %>%
  filter(pass_attempt==1) %>% mutate(year=substr(game_date,1,4))
```

Error is:

> Error: Problem with `mutate()` input `name_column`. x argument
> "name_column" is missing, with no default i Input `name_column` is
> `case_when(...)`. i The error occurred in group 1: year = "2018". Run
> `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.

I'm a bit confused as to why this would occur.

Is there an alternative to this function?

Here is an example dataframe to mess with:

```
 posteam pass_attempt yards_gained game_date   sack year 
   <chr>          <dbl>        <dbl> <chr>      <dbl> <chr>
 1 KC                 1          -30 2020-12-13     1 2020 
 2 CAR                1          -28 2019-12-01     1 2019 
 3 CHI                1          -28 2020-09-13     1 2020 
 4 NYJ                1          -28 2020-10-18     1 2020 
 5 ARI                1          -24 2020-12-06     1 2020 
 6 SEA                1          -22 2018-09-09     1 2018 
 7 CIN                1          -22 2020-10-25     1 2020 
 8 DEN                1          -21 2019-10-17     1 2019 
 9 JAX                1          -20 2020-09-20     1 2020 
10 LAC                1          -20 2020-12-27     1 2020
```

Comment: Those two are independent code chunks and should not affect one another. It does not produce any error for me. Make sure you have closed/completed the function correctly.

Comment: I cannot replicate your error, That said, be aware that `base::names` is a function from base that is very likely to be called by other functions and packages. I would choose another name for your custom function.

Comment: I believe Nicolás Velásquez, you were right.